# CString . Format issue

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have the following code snipppet.

```
double db = 1 / 1000000;
CString csStr("";
csStr.Format( '%.10f',ct);
```

Basically the value of `db` is `0.000001`.
I need to store this value as is in `csStr`.
Is the format statement correct in MFC VC++?
Also the `db` can be `1/100` or `1/100000000000`.

I must not store trucated values or rounded of value in `csStr`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems to deal with here:

1. Floating point types are not arbitrary precision types, so you can't store any value you want in them. Some values will have an exact floating point representation and some won't.
2. Even if you had an arbitrary precision type, you can't store its (general) string representation. I mean, if you calculate 1.0/3.0 and want to store its untruncated, unrounded result in a string, you will need infinite characters.

So what you ask is not possible, in general.

Now, the values you are asking about have an exact, finite-number-of-decimals, decimal representation (but not all of them an exact FP representation), and thanks to the rounding CString::Format does, you'll most likely get the correct value stored in csStr, if you do it well.

Your code has some issues (corrected so that it compiles):

```
double db = 1 / 1000000;    //  [1]
CString csStr("");          //  [2]
csStr.Format( "%.10f", db); //  [3]
```

[1] This stores 0.0 in db. It calculates the division as integers, which yields 0, then converts it to double. Do `double db = 1.0/1e6;` (or 1.0/1000000) instead.

[2] You don't need the initializer. CStrings are initialized as an empty string

[3]This will store "0.0000010000" in the string. <strike>If you don't want the trailing zeroes, write "%lf" as the format.</strike> According to the documentation, "the value is rounded to the appropriate number of digits". If the precision is enough, you'll get the right number, but it could be rounded to 0.0 if you don't have enough precision (e.g. if you specify a precision of 6 and the number is 0.00000001), or have trailing zeroes up to the precision specified.

So what to do? In your case, you say you'll have 1/100 or 1/100000000000. If that's true (you can only have those two values), and it's something that won't change (which will depend on what you are doing, but I would not trust that), you could store the divisor, and then create the string on the fly, with an `if` or something.

You could also use the "%g" format specification. It does the rounding too, but it removes any trailing zeroes. The caveat (or the good thing, depending on what you are doing) is that it can (and will) put some values in the "1e-6" format.